# grails 3.1 Exception - org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.ConnectionNotFoundException

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

Working with grails 3.1version, Getting this exception more often,mostly in production.

```
org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.ConnectionNotFoundException: No datastore session found. Call Datastore.connect(..) before calling Datastore.getCurrentSession()
    at grails.mongodb.MongoEntity$Trait$Helper.getDboInternal(MongoEntity.groovy:128) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at grails.mongodb.MongoEntity$Trait$Helper.getAt(MongoEntity.groovy:118) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at grails.mongodb.MongoEntity$Trait$Helper.propertyMissing(MongoEntity.groovy:60) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at my.fanfest.framework.UserController.updatememe(UserController.groovy:1115) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_95]
```

Any assistance to solve this exception would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to help you without any specific code which causes a problem. You can use this workaround:

```
SomeDomain.withNewSession { session -> 
   // your code here 
}
```